# Product version string from an exe - nsis

Tags: nsis

I want to read the product version ([optional string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ZCn.jpg))  from a given executable  (actually from the installer I'm trying to create if it makes any difference), if it is possible at the run-time. This string will be further used to download files from a link.

Thank you very much !

Comment: @Anders, the output of that function is                                               `DetailPrint:  "ProdVer: $R2.$R3.$R4.$R5"` .... and I need the actual values...

Comment: It works just fine for me but it gets the value at run-time and that is what you asked for ("keep it into a variable"). If you wanted it in a define at compile time then you should have asked for that...

Comment: @Anders , please forgive my lack of knowledge. I just want to use the installer's product version name (it is really just a name, not a something like xx.xx.xx.xx or whatever) in order to access a link for downloading some files needed for exactly that product version. I don't know any approach, and I thought about storing it in a `var` . Could you please tell me what are my choices or give me a valid example?

Comment: I already pointed you to something that gives you exactly what you asked for, getdllversion for the 64-bit product version stored in the fixed block in the version info.

Comment: @Anders , I do not know how to use it then...btw I'm using 32-bit system.

Comment: I was not talking about 64 vs 32 bit Windows. I was talking about the number stored in the version resource because at some point you said that you wanted the name and not xx.xx.xx.xx but getdllversion only gets that number so it is hard to tell what you actually want. Do you want the string or the number? Do you want it at compile time in a !define or at run-time in a $variable?

Comment: @Anders , sorry for my being unclear. For me xx.xx.xx.xx meant the file version of the exe , and I'm looking for the product version (which, in my case is simply a string). I think in a !define is the best.

Comment: What you don't understand is that what you call "Product Version" is actually two things, a number stored in [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx) and a optional string version of this number. GetDllVersion gets the version from VS_FIXEDFILEINFO.

Comment: @Anders , I'm looking for the optional string...

Comment: Well, you asked for a GetDllVersion that reads the product version. You should edit or delete this question and rephrase it in a way that makes it clear that you want the string. You also need to specify if you want it at compile-time or run-time. Compile-time is much harder and needs a hacky workaround. If you are passing the string to !system to perform the download then you need it at compile time...

Comment: @Anders ok, I modified the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSIS does not have native support for reading anything other than     [`VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646997(v=vs.85).aspx)`->dwFileVersion` so you have to call the Windows API directly:

```
; Add some version information so we have something to test
VIProductVersion 1.2.3.4
VIAddVersionKey "ProductVersion" "One Two Three Four"
VIAddVersionKey "FileVersion" "Whatever"
VIAddVersionKey "FileDescription" "Whatever"
VIAddVersionKey "LegalCopyright" "(C) Whatever"

!include LogicLib.nsh
Function GetFileVerFirstLangProductVersion
System::Store S
pop $3
push "" ;failed ret
System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfoSize(t"$3",i.r2)i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Alloc $0
    System::Call 'version::GetFileVersionInfo(t"$3",ir2,ir0,isr1)i.r0 ? e'
    pop $2
    ${If} $0 <> 0
    ${AndIf} $2 = 0 ;a user comment on MSDN said you should check GLE to avoid crash
        System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i r1,t "\VarFileInfo\Translation",*i0r2,*i0)i.r0'
        ${If} $0 <> 0
            System::Call '*$2(&i2.r2,&i2.r3)'
            IntFmt $2 %04x $2
            IntFmt $3 %04x $3
            System::Call 'version::VerQueryValue(i r1,t "\StringFileInfo\$2$3\ProductVersion",*i0r2,*i0r3)i.r0'
            ${If} $0 <> 0
                pop $0
                System::Call *$2(&t$3.s)
            ${EndIf}
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    System::Free $1
${EndIf}
System::Store L
FunctionEnd

Section
Push "$ExePath" ; Read our own version information in this example
Call GetFileVerFirstLangProductVersion
Pop $0
DetailPrint "ProductVersion=$0"
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Ok, I have a clearer view now. Thank you for taking your time to help me, it is highly appreciated.